# Reallocate the fraction of weights above threshold to the other weights while maintaining the sum per group

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `df1` with `Date` and `ID` as index and the `Weight`. I want to set an upper weight limit (30%) of the weights per date. The weights on each day add up to 100% and if I set an upper weight limit, it is the case that the next biggest weight is then bigger than the weight limit of 30%. Is there a way to account for that without doing several iterations? The remaining weight sum which are not bigger than the max weight add up to: 100% - number of max weights reached.

```
df1:
      Date ID  Weight
2023-01-30  A    0.45  <-- over max weight of 30%
2023-01-30  B    0.25
2023-01-30  C    0.15
2023-01-30  D    0.10
2023-01-30  E    0.05
2023-01-31  A    0.55
2023-01-31  B    0.25
2023-01-31  C    0.20
2023-01-31  D    0.00
2023-01-31  E    0.00

df1:
      Date ID  Weight  Weight_upper
2023-01-30  A    0.45         0.300 <-- set to max weight
2023-01-30  B    0.25         0.318 <-- bigger than max weight
2023-01-30  C    0.15         0.191
2023-01-30  D    0.10         0.127 (ex calculation: 0.1 * (1 - 0.3)/(0.25+0.15+0.1+0.05)
2023-01-30  E    0.05         0.060
2023-01-31  A    0.55         0.300
2023-01-31  B    0.25         0.389
2023-01-31  C    0.20         0.311
2023-01-31  D    0.00         0.000
2023-01-31  E    0.00         0.000
```

For reproducibility:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date':['2023-01-30', '2023-01-30', '2023-01-30', '2023-01-30', '2023-01-30', '2023-01-31', '2023-01-31', '2023-01-31', '2023-01-31', '2023-01-31'],
    'ID':['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
    'Weight':[0.45, 0.25, 0.15, 0.1, 0.05, 0.55, 0.25, 0.2, 0, 0]})
df.set_index('Date')
```

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: what would be your ideal output?

Comment: The ideal output would be a dataframe with a new column with the weights, where no single weight is bigger than the set max weight.

Comment: I proposed a method below, please have a look. It should ensure to keep the order of the weights and avoid going over threshold

Comment: Many thanks, that is exactly what I was trying to do!

Comment: Glad it worked, it was a fun question ;)

Answer (score 1):

The logic is unclear, so I'll assume you want to allocate the fraction of the weights above the desired max (0.3) to the other weights in a way that doesn't cause any other weight to become above threshold.

I would compute the difference to the threshold, then split the values into above/below and allocate the extra weight proportionally to the available space for each weight below threshold:

```
max_weight = 0.3

df2 = df.assign(diff=df['Weight'].sub(max_weight),
                mask=lambda d: d['diff'].gt(0),
                above=lambda d: d['diff'].where(d['mask']),
                below=lambda d: d['diff'].mask(d['mask']),
                )
g = df2.groupby('Date')

df['Weight_upper'] = (df2['below']
                      .div(g['below'].transform('sum'))
                      .mul(g['above'].transform('sum'))
                      .add(df['Weight'])
                      .fillna(max_weight)
                     )

print(df)
```

Output:

```
         Date ID  Weight  Weight_upper
0  2023-01-30  A    0.45      0.300000
1  2023-01-30  B    0.25      0.261538
2  2023-01-30  C    0.15      0.184615
3  2023-01-30  D    0.10      0.146154
4  2023-01-30  E    0.05      0.107692
5  2023-01-31  A    0.55      0.300000
6  2023-01-31  B    0.25      0.266667
7  2023-01-31  C    0.20      0.233333
8  2023-01-31  D    0.00      0.100000
9  2023-01-31  E    0.00      0.100000
```

Intermediates:

```
         Date ID  Weight  diff   mask  above  below  Weight_upper
0  2023-01-30  A    0.45  0.15   True   0.15    NaN      0.300000
1  2023-01-30  B    0.25 -0.05  False    NaN  -0.05      0.261538
2  2023-01-30  C    0.15 -0.15  False    NaN  -0.15      0.184615
3  2023-01-30  D    0.10 -0.20  False    NaN  -0.20      0.146154
4  2023-01-30  E    0.05 -0.25  False    NaN  -0.25      0.107692
5  2023-01-31  A    0.55  0.25   True   0.25    NaN      0.300000
6  2023-01-31  B    0.25 -0.05  False    NaN  -0.05      0.266667
7  2023-01-31  C    0.20 -0.10  False    NaN  -0.10      0.233333
8  2023-01-31  D    0.00 -0.30  False    NaN  -0.30      0.100000
9  2023-01-31  E    0.00 -0.30  False    NaN  -0.30      0.100000
```

Comment: I have one small remark to your great solution. Do you know how to adjust your solution to make sure that the second largest value (B) is set to the max value of 0.3 and not below (0.2615) and that D and E with zero weight remain at zero and get no weight of 0.1 assigned?